# Как поменять кодировку в массиве или при добавлении элемента в массив?

Tags: python

Паршу страницу и получаю цену товара и добавляю ее в массив, но она приходит в таком виде `6\u2009495\u2009₽` это равно `6495`

```
 with io.open(name[5:] + '.html', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    content = file.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
    for name in soup.select('div.ll4'):
        d = list(name.stripped_strings)
        data.append(d[1])
```

Как привести ее к нормальному виду?

Comment: Это символ "узкий пробел", можете просто убрать его из строки заменой: `data.append(d[1].replace(0x2009, ''))`

Comment: @CrazyElf ругается на то, что первый аргумент в replace должен быть строкой. если добавить кавычки к аргументу, то проблему не это не решает =(

Comment: .replace('\u2009', '')

Comment: @СергейШ спасибо!

Comment: print(''.join('6\u2009495\u2009₽'.split()[:-1])) #6495

Answer (score 0):

```
item = u'6\u2009495\u2009₽'
print(item) #6 495 ₽
```

укажите что строка Unicode символом "u"

Comment: u-строки были актуальны в Python 2